# Pyspark PCA Implementation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, pca

I am stuck in a problem where I wanna do PCA on a Pyspark Dataframe column. The name of the column is ‘features’ where each row is a SparseVector.

This is the flow:

Df - name of the pyspark df

Features - name of column

> Snippet of the rdd

[Row(features=SparseVector(2,{1:50.0})),

Row(features=SparseVector(2,{0:654.0, 1:20.0}))],

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
i   = RowMatrix(df.select(‘features’).rdd)
ipc = i.computePrincipalComponents(2)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viL2N.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an `RDD[Row]` object where your `Row` is `Row(features=SparseVector(2,{1:50.0}))`.

You need an `RDD[SparseVector]`, so you should change your line:

```
i = RowMatrix(df.select(‘features’).rdd)
```

to

```
i = RowMatrix(df.select(‘features’).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]))
```

which will return `RDD[SparseVector]`

Comment: Thank you but still not working. I have a new error ‘Cannot convert type <class ‘pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseVector’> into Vector.

Comment: Convert your SparseVector to Vector in the data frame

Comment: @HPZ001 Superb. Please upvote and select the answer if helped